# Using "exists?" inside a concern in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to move a method I was going to have in two models into a concern. My models are User and Provider. My module looks like this right now:

```
module ResetTokenable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  protected

  def generate_reset_token(column)
    begin
      self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
  end

end
```

In this scenario, how should I replace the reference to "User"? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be inclined to try

```
self.class.exists?
```

Someone will almost certainly come up with a better option though.